# How to fix Navbar design in React ?? Is there any change for Navbar design in Tailwind?

Tags: reactjs, navbar, tailwind-css

Initially I made a project and there the Navbar was completely ok. But I want to use the same Navbar on similar kind of project. But while type or copy paste the code the design is completely change. Even after a lot of search I can't find the actual problem as well as the solution also.

Both having same CSS file as well. Then where the problem occurs ?? Is there any change happened for Tailwind CSS design ?? Kindly let me know.

Navbar of previous project :
[image: Previous Working Navbar]

Navbar of present project :
[image: Present Project Navbar]

Even though all codes are same. I put all the Navbar code below.

````
import { HiMenuAlt4 } from 'react-icons/hi';
import { AiOutlineClose } from 'react-icons/ai';

import logo from '../../images/logo.png';

const NavbarItem = ({ title, classProps }) => {
    return (
        <li className={`mx-4 cursor-pointer ${classProps}`}>
            {title}
        </li>
    )
}

const Navbar = () => { 
    const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false); //Mobile View On or Not

    return (
        <nav className="w-full flex md:justify-center justify-between items-center p-4">
            <div className="md:flex-[0.5] flex-initial justify-center items-center">
                <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="w-32 cursor-pointer"/>

            </div>
            <ul className="text-white md:flex hidden list-none flex-row justify-between items-center flex-initial">
                {["Buy","Sell","Transfer","Wallets","About Us"].map((item, index) => (
                    <NavbarItem key={item + index} title={item} />
                ))}
                <li className="bg-[#3d4f79] py-2 px-7 mx-4 rounded-full cursor-pointer hover:bg-[#2546]">
                    SIGN IN
                </li>
            </ul>

            {/* Mobile View */}

            <div className="flex relative">
                {toggleMenu
                ? <AiOutlineClose fontSize={28} className="text-white md:hidden cursor-pointer" onClick={() => setToggleMenu(false)} />
                : <HiMenuAlt4 fontSize={28} className="text-white md:hidden cursor-pointer" onClick={() => setToggleMenu(true)} />
                }
                {toggleMenu && (
                    <ul
                        className="z-10 fixed top-0 -right-2 p-3 w-[70vw] h-screen shadow-2x1 md:hidden list-none 
                            flex flex-col justify-start items-end rounded-md blue-glassmorphism text-white animate-slide-in"
                        >
                        <li className="text-xl w-full my-2">
                            <AiOutlineClose onClick={() => setToggleMenu(false)} />
                        </li>
                        {["Market","Exchange","Tutorials","Wallets"].map((item, index) => (
                            <NavbarItem key={item + index} title={item} classProps="my-2 text-lg"/>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                )}
            </div>

        </nav>
    );
}

export default Navbar;```
````

Comment: **Answer** finally the error was founded by me... One of the most stupid mistake  ‍♂️.  Installed `npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest` on different directory. Actually I was a bit confused as a starter of React and Tailwind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding classname navbar fixed `<nav className="fixed w-full flex md:justify-center justify-between items-center p-4">`